# Tikz Intersecion doesn't recognize path named with name path

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, paths, naming, intersections

I have problems with using path names defined even in the same loop. the following code produces error message:

```
 ! Package tikz Error: I do not know the path named `ab6'. Perhaps you misspelt it.
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,chains,positioning,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
%
%
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\begin{document}
%
\center
\tdplotsetmaincoords{47}{5}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,tdplot_main_coords]
\foreach\i in {0,...,6}
{\tdplotsetcoord{A\i}{1}{8+51.4*\i}{0};
\coordinate(B\i) at ([shift={(0,1.2,0)}]A\i);}
\foreach \k[evaluate=\k as \ki using {int(mod(\k+3,7))}] in {0,...,6}
{\path[%draw%
,thick,name path = pa\k](A\k)--(A\ki);
\path[%draw%
,thick,name path = pb\k](B\k)--(B\ki);
}
\foreach \j in {0,...,6}
{%\node at (C\j){$C_\j$};
\node at (A\j){$A_\j$};
%\node at (D\j){$D_\j$};
\node at (B\j){$B_\j$};
}
\foreach \j[evaluate={\ja={int(mod(\j+2,7))};\jc={int(mod(\j+6,7))}}] in  {0,...,6}
{
\path[name path=ba\j,draw](B\j)--(A\ja);
\path[name path=ab\j,draw](A\j)--(B\ja);
\path[name intersections={of={ba\j} and {ab\jc},by={C\j}}];
}
%\path[name intersections={of={ba0} and {ab6},by={C0}}]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've tried

```
name path global
```

and

```
name path globa/.expanded
```

but neither helps. When I comment the line causing this problem and uncomment

```
\path[name intersections={of={ba0} and {ab6},by={C0}}]
```

Then TikZ says it doesn't know the path named `ba0'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first iteration of the loop `\j` is 0 but `\jc` is 6 and you are trying to do

```
  \path[name intersections={of={ba\j} and {ab\jc},by={C\j}}];
```

that is, finding intersections of `ba0` and `ab6`, but `ab6` doesn't yet exist. Use two separate loops:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,chains,positioning,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{47}{5}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,tdplot_main_coords]
\foreach\i in {0,...,6}
{\tdplotsetcoord{A\i}{1}{8+51.4*\i}{0};
\coordinate(B\i) at ([shift={(0,1.2,0)}]A\i);}
\foreach \k[evaluate=\k as \ki using {int(mod(\k+3,7))}] in {0,...,6}
{\path[%draw%
,thick,name path = pa\k](A\k)--(A\ki);
\path[%draw%
,thick,name path = pb\k](B\k)--(B\ki);
}
\foreach \j in {0,...,6}
{%\node at (C\j){$C_\j$};
\node at (A\j){$A_\j$};
%\node at (D\j){$D_\j$};
\node at (B\j){$B_\j$};
}

\foreach \j [evaluate={\ja={int(mod(\j+2,7))};\jc={int(mod(\j+6,7))}}] in  {0,...,6}
{
\path[name path global=ba\j,draw](B\j)--(A\ja);
\path[name path global=ab\j,draw](A\j)--(B\ja);
}

\foreach \j [evaluate={\ja={int(mod(\j+2,7))};\jc={int(mod(\j+6,7))}}] in  {0,...,6}
  \path[name intersections={of={ba\j} and {ab\jc},by={C\j}}];

\path[name intersections={of={ba0} and {ab6},by={C0}}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```